# Getting number of clusters and its markers with Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, clustering, markers

I would like to know the number of clusters and its markers as soon as I open the map without zoom-in.

I'm using:

- Leaflet 1.2.0
- Leaflet.MarkerCluster 1.2.0
- Firefox 57.0.1
- OS/Platform

On the image below the expected result is demonstrated. It should represent:

- 1 cluster with 6 markers (marker1, marker2, marker4, marker5, marker6, marker7)
- for each marker its details (name, lat, lon, ...)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For total number of markers/layers you can use the `getLayers()` function which will return an array of all the component layers of that cluster.

```
var testCluster = L.markerClusterGroup();
L.marker([event.latlng.lat, event.latlng.lng]).addTo(testCluster);
testCluster.getLayers();
```

It will return array of each marker as layer.

Alternatively You can use this:

```
map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        if (layer.getChildCount){     
            console.log(layer._childClusters.length)        
            console.log(layer._childCount);  
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Leaflet markerCluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#customising-the-clustered-markers) `getChildCount()` and `getAllChildMarkers()` methods
From the manual:
"As an option to MarkerClusterGroup you can provide your own function for creating the Icon for the clustered markers....
You are passed a MarkerCluster object, you'll probably want to use getChildCount() or getAllChildMarkers() to work out the icon to show "